# Who is the winner in the zero-sum game?

Tags: game-theory

I have a zero-sum game as described in the table below:

- Using minimax = maximin approach I get that the first player should play A with $p^*=\frac{5}{12}$ and B with $p^*=\frac{7}{12}$.
- The second player should then mix A and B with $q^*=\frac{1}{2}$.
- I found the value of the game to be: $v=0.5$.

The question is asking to determine the winner. And since, the game is zero-sum, I know that
one player wins and the other loses (what is one player's gain is the
other's loss etc.). But how does this apply to this situation?
Basically, every time they play the same action, player 2 wins and
when they play different actions - player 1 wins. But how to
determine the overall winner? I think it is based on the value of the
game. My guess is that when the value of the game, v is positive,
then the first player is the winner? Is that correct?

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} 
 & \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{min} \\ \hline
\text{A} & -3 & 4 & -3\\ \hline
\text{B} & 3 & -2 & -2 \\ \hline
\text{max} & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: Your analysis is correct. If you look at a single game, either can win, whereas if you look at the long term average if the game is played repeatedly, $A$ wins.

Comment: It seems $A$ is not a player, but a strategy.  The players are "first" and "second".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "overall winner".  Value $v=0.5$, means that (when the two players use the specified "optimal" strategies) then the first player's winnings average $0.5$ per play.  Because of the random nature of the play, he wins some and loses some.  If one player does not use the optimal strategy, then that $0.5$ will change in the other player's favor.

Comment: So, on average, player 1 wins 0.5 per day and player 2 loses 0.5 per day? If I was to allow them to play only 1 day, wouldn't it make player 1 a winner?

Comment: It is more likely that 1 wins than 2, but it is not certain that 1 wins.  So I would not say "1 is a winner".

Comment: To add to this answer, if we subtract 0.5 from all payoffs we get an equivalent game but with a value of $0$. If we subtract 100 from all payoffs, then the value will be negative. Will it make Player 2 suddenly the winner of this game?

Answer (score 0):

The row player has an expected payout of $0.5$ and the column player has an expected payout of $-0.5$, so if you judge the winner on their expected payout from playing the mixed strategies the row player is the winner.

Comment: This is precisely the intuition I wanted to use. But wasn't sure if it's the correct one.